# Change color of pulsing blue ring around user's location

Tags: ios, mapkit

I've scoured the web and haven't found a way to customize the color of the blue pulsing ring around the user's location on a map.

Does anyone know a way to customize the color of the pulsing ring?

Comment: You will have to make your own annotation view and provide your own animation.

Answer (score 10):

The blue color for the user location is based on the tint color of your map view, changing this will set the new color for the user location circle.

```
//Objective-C 
mapView.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];

//Swift 4.2
mapView.tintColor = UIColor.red
```

Comment: I have tried hard but not succeed, Can you please help me , can you send me sample code or something?

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 3

```
mapView.tintColor = UIColor.red
```

or use Color Literal

[image]