# How to change color of bubble for user's location in MapKit?

Tags: swift, mapkit

The map view shows the user's location with a default blue bubble animation. How can I change that default blue color to another color?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change color of pulsing blue ring around user's location](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23208835/change-color-of-pulsing-blue-ring-around-users-location)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can change the `tintColor` of the `mapView` with:

```
mapView.tintColor = UIColor.greenColor()
```

Put this in the `viewDidLoad()` of the `ViewController` where your `mapView` is embedded.

Comment: If this does not work, you may need to add `mapView.tintAdjustmentMode = .normal`

Answer (score 0):

In swift 3 try with color literal

```
mapView.tintColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9607843137, green: 0.5764705882, blue: 0.003921568627, alpha: 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the color of User Location Bubble by

**step 1**

[image]

**step 2**

[image]

**step 3**
Change the **Tint** Color

[image]